# Having trouble with authentication in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization

I am trying to authenticate users who are logging into my web application from a log-in page.  I was using [this tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240) as a guide, which pretty much explained exactly what I'm hoping to do, but when I enter in the username and password, the validation is not working.  Allow me to explain.

Here are relevant parts of my HTML.  Nothing out of the ordinary:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class=row>
<div class=col-xs-4>
    <div class="form-group">
<input id="txtUserName" type="text" runat="server">
<ASP:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
       Display="Static" ErrorMessage="*" runat="server" 
       ID="vUserName" />
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class=row>
<div class=col-xs-4>
<div class="form-group">
        <input id="txtUserPass" type="password" runat="server">
<ASP:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtUserPass"
      Display="Static" ErrorMessage="*" runat="server" 
      ID="vUserPass" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p><asp:Label ID="lblMsg" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" /></p>
<input type="submit" Value="Logon" runat="server" ID="cmdLogin"><p></p>
<ASP:CheckBox id="chkPersistCookie" runat="server" autopostback="false" />
</form>
```

The page contains a username and a button to login (and a checkbox for remembering cookies but I don't think that's relevant to my problem).

Here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MRAApplication
{
    public partial class _1__0__0__0_LoginScreen : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.cmdLogin.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.cmdLogin_ServerClick);
        }

        private bool ValidateUser(string userName, string passWord)
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            string lookupPassword = null;

            // Check for invalid userName.
            // userName must not be null and must be between 1 and 15 characters.
            if ((null == userName) || (0 == userName.Length) || (userName.Length > 15))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Input validation of userName failed.");
                return false;
            }

            // Check for invalid passWord.
            // passWord must not be null and must be between 1 and 25 characters.
            if ((null == passWord) || (0 == passWord.Length) || (passWord.Length > 25))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Input validation of passWord failed.");
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                // Consult with your SQL Server administrator for an appropriate connection
                // string to use to connect to your local SQL Server.
                conn = new SqlConnection("databaseConnect");
                conn.Open();

                // Create SqlCommand to select pwd field from users table given supplied userName.
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Password from Users where User=@userName", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
                cmd.Parameters["@userName"].Value = userName;

                // Execute command and fetch pwd field into lookupPassword string.
                lookupPassword = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                // Cleanup command and connection objects.
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Add error handling here for debugging.
                // This error message should not be sent back to the caller.
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Exception " + ex.Message);
            }

            // If no password found, return false.
            if (null == lookupPassword)
            {
                // You could write failed login attempts here to event log for additional security.
                return false;
            }

            // Compare lookupPassword and input passWord, using a case-sensitive comparison.
            return (0 == string.Compare(lookupPassword, passWord, false));

        }

        private void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value, txtUserPass.Value))
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
                string cookiestr;
                HttpCookie ck;
                tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now,
          DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "your custom data");
                cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
                ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
                if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
                    ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration;
                ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
                Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

                string strRedirect;
                strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
                if (strRedirect == null)
                    strRedirect = "default.aspx";
                Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
            }
            else
                Response.Redirect("1.0.0.0_LoginScreen.aspx", true);
        }
     }
    }
```

Now, I've tested my connection string and it works.  It's connecting to a table in a SQL Server database which contains 3 columns of User, Password, and UserRole.  Right now I just have a single test entry in the table, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa7kH.jpg).

However, when I run the application and enter "test" into "txtUserName" and "password" into "txtUserPass" and click "submit" it is redirecting back to the login page, which means it is returning false for "if (ValidateUser(txtUserName.Value, txtUserPass.Value))".

If anybody could help me with this error I would appreciate it.  Thank you for your help.  :)

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET <form>?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I am, somehow it got cut out of the code I pasted here though.  Edited for clarity.

Comment: @JaGo If you set a break point at `if (ValidateUser(txtUse..`, what is the return value - true or false? How do you create **IPrincipal** in **AuthenticateRequest**?

Comment: sounds like you need to learn how to use the debugger as well as how to setup Event handlers. I would look at some `IsPostBack` code and learn how to use that as well.. looks very sloppy

Comment: Try by adding FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName,true) before redirecting

Comment: @Partha OP creates the authentication cookie manually. You should not use **SetAuthCookie** if you create cookie manually; it'll override  **cookie expiration date**.

Comment: @Win I hope this is not too frustrating but I'm very new to programming and this is my first time trying to do authentication so I'm not totally sure how to get the return value by using the breakpoint.  When I put a breakpoint on the line you mentioned, the login screen runs as normal, and when I press logon, Visual studio pops up with the "if" line highlighted.  The browser begins loading but doesn't do anything else.


As for the IPrincipal question, can you explain what that is to me.  Embarrassingly, I don't know what that is. :(


I do sincerely appreciate your time though.

Comment: Put a break point in validateuser function. It will go inside that function. You can check your values there too

Comment: Maybe some issue in web.config ? 
@JaGo can you pls show us your authentication/authorization part of web.config ?

Comment: @Partha 


`<authentication mode="Forms">
      
<forms loginUrl="1.0.0.0_LoginScreen.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
        protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
   
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users ="?" />
     <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>`

Trying to format this best as possible...:/

Comment: <allow users = "*" />. 
Remove this. You deny anonymous users with ?. No need of allow users="*"

Comment: @Partha Okay, thanks.  Original issue is still persisting though.  I really appreciate your time btw, sorry if I'm frustrating, I'm very new to coding.

Comment: No prob. Even I learnt a new thing from @Win today.

Comment: Did you try keeping the break point in validate function and debugged it ?

Comment: @Partha where specifically should I put the breakpoint?  On the line "if (ValidateUser(textUserName.Value, txtUserPass.Value))"?  And what should I be looking for after I run after that?  When I put a breakpoint on the line you mentioned, the login screen runs as normal, and when I press logon, Visual studio pops up with the "if" line highlighted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60556/discussion-between-partha-and-jago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is my first time trying to do authentication so I'm not totally
>   sure how to get the return value by using the breakpoint.

You want to test with hard-coded username and password before connecting to SQL server.

```
protected void cmdLogin_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.Equals(txtUserName.Value, "johndoe", 
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
        String.Equals(txtUserPass.Value, "123456", 
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var roles = new[] {"Administrators"};

        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
            txtUserName.Value,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
            chkPersistCookie.Checked,
            string.Join(",", roles),
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
            FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));

        if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
            cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        string returnUrl = Request["ReturnUrl"];
        if (returnUrl == null)
            returnUrl = "default.aspx";
        Response.Redirect(returnUrl, true);
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect("1.0.0.0_LoginScreen.aspx", true);
}
```

### How to create Principal Object

When an authenticated user is requested a page, you need to retrieve auth ticket from cookie, and create a Principal object.

```
// Global.asax.cs
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie decryptedCookie =
            Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (decryptedCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =
                FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(decryptedCookie.Value);

            string[] roles = ticket.UserData.Split(new[] {","}, 
                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var identity = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);

            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string username = User.Identity.Name;

            bool isAdministrator = User.IsInRole("Administrators");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  The authentication works when I'm using "johndoe", so that means the problem must be with getting the info from SQL Server, right?

Comment: I gotta say **yes**. Connecting to SQL Server is different animal; a lot of things can go wrong easily. So take your time and study how to debug web application first. Otherwise, you'll get frustrated easily. Good luck!

Comment: Okay, cool.  I was able to populate a table with data from the same database and same connectionstring elsewhere in my application, so I'm guessing it must be something I'm doing wrong within "cmdLogin_ServerClick".  I'll look into what the issue is.

You've been very helpful, I owe you one, Win.