# Singleton Design Pattern in a web environment

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, web-applications

I'm using in my asp.net web site, a singleton class to the users information.

I would like to know, if I put this web site online, when the users start to login, this this class will store the data to only one user.

This is my class:

```
public class User
{
    private static User instance;        
    private User(){}

    public static User Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new User();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public Institute LoggedInstitute { get; set; }
    public List<Institute> Institutes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please share your code to assess so that we will be able to respond

Comment: `public class User
{
    private static User instance;        
    private User(){}

    public static User Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new User();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
 
 public Institute LoggedInstitute { get; set; }
    public List<Institute> Institutes { get; set; }
}
`

Comment: I tried to put the word wrap.. but didn't work... :(

Comment: You should put your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the users start to login, this this class will store the data to
>   only one user.

There will be only one instance of User exists in your application.

***Storing each user information in Singleton is a very very very bad idea for web application. Why?***

Multiple users request your web application, and they all will share the same instance of User. I guarantee that it is not what you want.

Ideally, in web application, you want to create **Principal** object, and store it in **HttpContext**.

***FYI:*** we use Singleton in web application to store information (mostly never change) which is used beginning of the application until the end.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25649625/296861) regarding how to create Principal object.

Answer (score 0):

There will only be multiple instances of your class if your application is used in a web farm scenario. Refer to this thread: [Are static class instances unique to a request or a server in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194999/are-static-class-instances-unique-to-a-request-or-a-server-in-asp-net)

Comment: So, just to confirm, if I log in the application, using my credentials, and after me another user log in the application, it will get my user data?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use a static to store the User? If you want this information to be unique per session - you should store this information in Session.

Comment: Because the data volumn size

Answer (score 0):

Static fields in C# (and I believe in all .NET languages), such as the one used to hold the singleton instance of your `User` class, are "unique" within an [`AppDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx).

If, and only if, you have multiple AppDomains, whether in the same process, in another process, or on another machine (such as in a web farm), as William pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012233/singleton-design-pattern-in-a-web-environment#31012603), you could have multiple instances.

[Scope of static variables in ASP.NET sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390248/scope-of-static-variables-in-asp-net-sites)

[In .Net is the 'Staticness' of a public static variable limited to an AppDomain or the whole process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562162/in-net-is-the-staticness-of-a-public-static-variable-limited-to-an-appdomain)